# Simple login program using C

Tags: c

So, I'm working on an extra lab task which require me to build a simple login program to read studentID and password using C. i tried to use strcmp() to verify the ID and password but even tho the elements compared are correct, the program will always display "Wrong Password". Please help me take a look on my program, any helps are appreciated. Thanks in advance

Following are my coding:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char studentID[]="Clarance", password[]="123456", id[8], p[6];
    int n=1, x, y;

    do{
         printf("\nStudent_ID:");
         scanf("%s", &id);

         printf("\nPassword:");
         scanf("%s", &p);

         x=strcmp(id, studentID);
         y=strcmp(p, password);

         if(x==0 && y==0){
           printf("\nSucessfully Logged In");
         }else {
           printf("\nWrong Password, try again", 5-n);
            getch();
            n++;}

         if(n>5){
          printf("\nAccess Denied");
          getch();
          }

       }while (n<=5);

}
```

Comment: Go with debugger. I am pretty sure you have trailing newline charcter in the read password. And moreover, please read this. You have a buffer overflow vulnerability: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/buffer-overflow/

Comment: Your `id` and `p` arrays are one too small to hold the correct ID and password. Furthermore, please study how to use a debugger, as examining the input arrays would probably have shown you things going wrong.

Comment: There are multiple possible problems: The first is that your `scanf` calls are prone to buffer overflows. If the user enters more than 7 characters for the `id` and more than 5 characters for `p`, you will go out of bounds of your buffers. And the reason for the `7` and `5` character limits is that you forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. The *null-terminated* bit is important, and is what makes a string a string. It does of course need its own element in your arrays.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked! I did it by increasing both the "id" and "p" arrays to 20

Comment: Increasing the size of the arrays has solved the problem and works. But it's not a good thing. This way your program will compare `Clarence\n` and `123456\n` which is not exactly what you want to compare. It works anyway. It would be more correct to clean the buffer every time, it is a useless fuss in this program, but knowing it will be very useful in the programs you will write tomorrow.

Comment: @kitsune which `\n` are you talking about? `scanf` with `%s` doesn't leave a `\n` at the end of the string.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You're right, I'm wrong, the scnaf does not take that character. However, I tried again to run the code and I solved it by simply changing this: `static const char studentID[]="Clarance", password[]="123456";` , leaving the rest as Marco posted it.

Comment: This is what I get running its program: `ID stored: ''
ID read: 'Clarance'
Password stored: ''
Password read: '123456'
Wrong Password, try again`

Comment: You need to get a newer source of learning C. conio.h reeks of early 1990s MS DOS programming.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is **how** you declared constant strings.

This is what I get running your program:

```
...
char studentID[]="Clarance", password[]="123456";
...

ID stored: ''
ID read: 'Clarance'
Password stored: ''
Password read: '123456'
Wrong Password, try again
```

and this is what I get by changing the declaration of the strings:

```
...
static const char studentID[]="Clarance", password[]="123456";
...
ID stored: 'Clarance'
ID read: 'Clarance'
Password stored: '123456'
Password read: '123456'
Sucessfully Logged In
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    static const char studentID[]="Clarance", password[]="123456";
    char id[8], p[6];
    int n=1, x, y;

    printf("%lu %lu:", strlen(id), strlen(studentID));


    do{
        printf("\nStudent_ID:");
        scanf("%s", &id);
        fflush(stdout);

        printf("\nPassword:");
        scanf("%s", &p);
        fflush(stdout);

        x=strcmp(id, studentID);
        y=strcmp(p, password);

        if(x==0 && y==0){
            printf("\nSucessfully Logged In");
        }else {
            printf("\nWrong Password, try again", 5-n);
            getchar();
            n++;}

        if(n>5){
            printf("\nAccess Denied");
            getchar();
        }

    }while (n<=5);

}
```

The problem was you missing `flush(stdio);`.

Whenever you use `scanf`, it is a good idea to clean the standard input read buffer. The x function allows this to be done.

---

**Notes about developing**:

```
rm myprog; gcc -o myprog main.c; ./myprog
rm: myprog: No such file or directory
main.c:16:21: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[8]' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%s", &id);
               ~~   ^~~
main.c:20:21: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[6]' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%s", &p);
               ~~   ^~
main.c:34:51: warning: data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
            printf("\nWrong Password, try again", 5-n);
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
3 warnings generated.
```

Learn to use the debugger. A very simple one is provided by the gcc command. Look at my output. From this it is clear that your program works, but it is not perfect because there are three warnings. Study a little bit over and try to calmly understand what they mean and try to figure out how you can solve them.

Debuggers are very important during software development.

---

**Notes about constant strings**:

Always keep in mind that variables or objects such as username and password usually come from a database, but in the case of your program that is simple and has educational purposes it is a good idea to fix these variables so that they can not be changed during the execution of your program. In other words, assign the read-only property to the username and password variables. In the code I posted I made these changes.

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work for me. Not sure what I missed tho. But anyway thanks for the advices. I think i need to work hard on the debugger

Answer (score 0):

Here are my own version of solution. I know it's simple but it worked

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char studentID[]="Clarance", password[]="123456", id[20], p[20];
    int n=1, x, y;

    do{
         printf("\nStudent_ID:");
         scanf("%s", &id);
         fflush(stdout);

         printf("\nPassword:");
         scanf("%s", &p);
         fflush(stdout);

         x=strcmp(id, studentID);
         y=strcmp(p, password);

         if(x==0 && y==0){
           printf("\nSucessfully Logged In");
           break;
         }else {
           printf("\nWrong Password, try again", 5-n);
            getch();
            n++;}

         if(n>5){
          printf("\nAccess Denied");
          getch();
          }

       }while (n<=5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Array size for p[] and id[] is the same as string length. Actually we need to provide array size of (length+1).This is to take into consideration the Null character at the end. strcmp compares both strings until Null character.

So Following will be the arrays declared. 
char p[7],id[9];

If you don't wish to increase the array size, please try strncmp(), where a third argument can be provided to specify total number of characters to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char password [1000];
    printf("Hi there, please enter your password to verify if you are Samarth Matam: ");
    gets(password);
    if(strcmp(password, "Password")==0)
    {
        printf("Okay! You are Samarth Matam, hence you are allowed!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong password!");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char LoginId[100];
    char Password[100];

    while(1){
    printf("Welcome to the Login_System\n");
    printf("Please Enter your LoginID\n");
    gets(LoginId);
    printf("Please Enter your Password\n");
    gets(Password);
    if(strcmp(LoginId,"User")==0){
        if(strcmp(Password,"12345")==0){
            printf("Hey,You are Welcome\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Try Again!!\n");
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will is a simple program that asks for Login and Password until user provides the correct credentials

Comment: But what is wrong with the program in the question?